# Discord normal user channel ids JS

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to send a message to everyone I'm friends with in Discord, but there are many I can't reach through normal means. Is there a way to get everyone's channel ID using the GET method or something similar?

```js
const channelsIds = [] // i am trying to get all my account channelsIds useing someway maybe discord api or something like that
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader(
  "Authorization",
  "the thing here "
);
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.onload = () => {
  console.log(xhr.response);
};
xhr.send();
```

I'm currently looking for an API with which I can achieve this goal or something similar.